# How to set arbitrary dependency on source file in automake, without a generated source

Tags: makefile, automake

I have a problem with depdency ordering of a source file which includes a generated file.  For example, in a file called `unit.cpp` I have this:

```
 #include "generated.hpp"
```

Where `generated.hpp` is a generated file and will be produced in the output include directories.  Now, this file is generated via an intermediate command, with a makefile rule such as:

```
 .build-generated:
     cmd.sh ... > include/generated.hpp
     touch $@
```

The building of the `unit.o` file thus requires that `.build-generated` is called first. If I do the following I confuse the resulting makefile:

```
 unit.cpp: .build-generated
```

Since the make will now assume that `unit.cpp` is a generated file and ignore the one in the source directory (only if .build-generated has to be remade). I've looked at the verbose make output and it says it is ignoring the one in the VPATH.

In a normal makefile I might make `unit.o` depend on the other target, but this doesn't appear to be the automake way (as it may not be portable). *It actually doesn't even work, since the target may be a `.lo` file instead*

How can I properly tell automake about this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

As per the automake manual, you are to specify it per:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = generated.hpp
```

Comment: I saw that as well, but then it only builds if you run `make all` or some other global target. I would like to build on individual targets since that is our typical dev process (building only sub-targets while working on something).

Answer (score 0):

If you use autoconf with automake, you can depend your source file from your header:

```
$srcdir/unit.cpp : $builddir/include/generated.hpp
```

If `$builddir` doesn't suits you ( for example, you can use common header included in several Makefile.am ), use `$top_builddir`. Other useful autoconf variables can be found [here](http://file://localhost/P:/docs/gnu/autoconf.html#Preset-Output-Variables).

Comment: This doesn't work, it is was I tried first. It may be a defect however. When the dependency is outdated it fails to find unit.cpp -- in verbose mode it explicitly says it is ignoring the VPATH one found.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper solution is to have the object files depend on the generated headers:

```
include/generated.hpp:
     cmd.sh ... > include/generated.hpp
     touch $@
unit.o: include/generated.hpp
```

In case of using automake, something like

```
$(prog_OBJECTS): include/generated.hpp
```